# Repeated differentiation of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$

Tags: calculus

Let $g(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. I want to calculate the n-th derivative of $g(x)$ at $x=0,x=1$.

For $x=0$, I wrote $g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{2n}$ from the geometric series. This says that $g^{(2k+1)}(0)=0$ and $g^{(4k)}(0)=1$, $g^{(4k+2)}(0)=-1$ right?

For the $x=1$ case how can it be calculated?

Comment: For $x=0$, be careful about the factorials that should come up when comparing coefficients to derivatives. For $x=1$, try changing variables to $u=x-1$. This makes the expansion about $u=0$ which may be easier. (Alternatively, write $g(x)$ in terms of $(x-1)$ and expand with that being small.) It'll still be more complicated than the $x=0$ case; try to see a pattern.

Comment: $0^0$ needs to be interpreted to be $1$. All other $0^n$ are $0$.

Comment: @alex.jordan Sorry I didn't understand your comment

Comment: When you are evaluating $g^{(4k)}(0)$, you do should not get $0$ as the result. The first term in the series involves $x^0$, and with $x=0$, that term is nonzero.

Comment: Sorry, I see now that you see that. Still, why are there no powers appearing? For example, $g^{(2)}(x)=\sum(-1)^n(2n)(2n-1)x^{2n-2}$, and so $g^{(2)}(0)=(2(1))(2(1)-1)=2$, not $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac1{x^2+1}=\frac1{(x+i)(x-i)}=\frac1{2i}\left(\frac{x+i-(x-i)}{(x+i)(x-i)}\right)=\frac1{2i}\left(\frac1{x-i}-\frac1{x+i}\right)$$

Now $\displaystyle\frac{d[(x+a)^{-1}]}{dx}=-(x+a)^{-2}$

$\displaystyle\frac{d^2[(x+a)^{-1}]}{dx^2}=(-1)(-2)(x+a)^{-3},$

$\displaystyle\frac{d^3[(x+a)^{-1}]}{dx^3}=(-1)(-2)(-3)(x+a)^{-4}=(-1)^3(3!)(x+a)^{-4},$

So, $\displaystyle\frac{d^n[(x+a)^{-1}]}{dx^n}=(-1)^nn!(x+a)^{-(n+1)}$ for integer $n\ge0$

Put $\displaystyle x=r\cos\theta,1=r\sin\theta$

Then put the values of $x$ one  by one

Comment: I didn't understand the part "Put $x=rcosθ,1=rsinθ$"

Comment: @user150391,It will allow us to utilize http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula

Answer (score 0):

For the case $x=0$, write the series to get:
$$\frac{d^k}{dx^k}\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac{d^k}{dx^k}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^{2n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{(2n)!}{(2n-k)!}x^{2n-k}$$
Then evaluation at $x=0$ gives you $0$ if $k$ is odd, and $(-1)^{\frac{k}{2}}k!$ if $k$ is even.

For $x=1$ instead you can do the same as above using the change of variables $y=x-1$, so that you have:
$$g(x)\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{(x-1)^2+2(x-1)+2}=\frac{1}{y^2+2y+2}=f(y)$$
and $g(1)=f(0)$ (and similarly for all derivatives).